# Speeding up access to a array with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv

I am trying to make a fast image threshold function. Currently what I do is:

```
void threshold(const cv::Mat &input, cv::Mat &output, uchar threshold) {

    int rows = input.rows;
    int cols = input.cols;

    // cv::Mat for result
    output.create(rows, cols, CV_8U);        

    if(input.isContinuous()) { //we have to make sure that we are dealing with a continues memory chunk

        const uchar* p;

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {

            p = input.ptr<uchar>(r);

            for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {

                if(p[c] >= threshold)
                    //how to access output faster??
                    output.at<uchar>(r,c) = 255;
                else
                    output.at<uchar>(r,c) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the `at()` function is quite slow. How can I set the output faster, or in other words how to relate the pointer which I get from the input to the output?

Comment: you already got p[c] . manipulate that instead of retrieving with at() a second time (it won't get any faster than that) - and again, you're trying  to beat the opencv devs on their own turf - don't, ever, you can only loose ;)

Comment: @Saeid Yazdani ``at`` [indeed checks this stuff](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/).

Comment: ... in DEBUG mode only

Comment: @AmiTavory This is not `at` of the standard library, this is OpenCV.

Comment: @berak Thanks. I am doing some testing...it doesn't hurt to test. I timed `cv::threshold` function and its blazing fast I already know!

Comment: SSE, opencl optimizations, and what not

Comment: I swear I saw some docs regarding `Mat.at()`  which says its slow because it does check for bounds and stuff...can't find the link now...

Comment: don't mess with jabberwocky

Comment: @SaeidYazdani have you tried getting row pointer using output.ptr<uchar>(r), and using it in your internal loop? Also if output is initially zero initialized then you dont need to store zero in else part.

Comment: @marcinj, stare hard at the code above, - it's already there.

Comment: @berak question is `how to access output faster??`, so my idea is to substitute `output.at<uchar>(r,c)` to bare pointer operation.

Comment: get a pointer to the 1st row element,  use sse instructions. (or , neon, or cuda, or, opencl, whatever available) - again, do not try to mess with a solved problem.

Comment: @berak I can't figure out what you mean by manipulating `p[c]` and relating it to output...any help pls?

Comment: p[c] = (p[c]>=threshold) ? 255 : 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) as the C++ standard library documents it for a few containers, performing a range check and throwing if out of bounds, however this is not the standard library but OpenCV.

According to the [cv::Mat::at](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) documentation:

> The template methods return a reference to the specified array element. **For the sake of higher performance, the index range checks are only performed in the Debug configuration**.

So there's no range check as you may be thinking.

Comparing both [`cv::Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) and [`cv::Mat::ptr`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) in the source code we can see they are almost identical.

So [cv::Mat::ptr<>(row)](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/a26ab3ab1617c075da3aa5eb123a3a10df08081f/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L772) is as expensive as

```
return (_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * y);
```

While [cv::Mat::at<>(row, column)](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/a26ab3ab1617c075da3aa5eb123a3a10df08081f/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L895) is as expensive as:

```
return ((_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * i0))[i1];
```

You might want to take [`cv::Mat::ptr`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) directly instead of calling [`cv::Mat::at`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) every column to avoid further repetition of the `data + step.p[0] * i0` operation, doing `[i1]` by yourself.

So you would do:

```
/* output.create and stuff */

const uchar* p, o;

for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {

    p = input.ptr<uchar>(r);
    o = output.ptr<uchar>(r); // <-----

    for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c) {

        if(p[c] >= threshold)
           o[c] = 255;
          else
            o[c] = 0;
    }
}
```

As a side note you don't and shouldn't check for [`cv::Mat::isContinuous`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#bool%20Mat::isContinuous%28%29%20const) here, the gaps are from one row to another, you are taking pointers to a single row, so you don't need to deal with the matrix gaps.

Comment: can you please tell me what do you mean bu on a row? code sample if possible please!

Comment: @SaeidYazdani The row of the matrix! Anyway I've edited my post with a lot more of information.